# Search array index with double quotes string using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

File1:

```
"1"|data|er

"2"|text|rq

""|test2|req

"3"|test4|teq
```

File2:

```
1

2

3
```

Expected Output should be (file3.txt)

```
"1"|data|er

"2"|text|rq

"3"|test4|teq
```

```
awk -F''$Delimeter'' '{print $1}' file1.txt | awk '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); print $1}' | awk  'NF && !seen[$1]++' | sort -n > file2.txt
```

I am able to extract the ids 1,2,3 from file1 and removed the double quotes and written into the file2 but i need to search these 1,2,3 ids in my file1.txt("1","2","3"), problem is search not recognizing due to dobule qoutes in the file

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} \"$1\" in a' file2.txt file1.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is your goal ? From inout `File1` you want to obtain `File3` ? `File2` is only a temporary file ? If so, then you need to extract from `file1` the lines that contains numbers in their first field ?

Comment: I need to extract ids from file1 and create file2 with ids should not contain double quotes. finally search file2 ids(1,2,3) in file1 get the matching records. ultimately ids not recognizing the double quotes when searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v s1='"' '
FNR==NR{
  val=s1 $0 s1
  a[val]
  next
}
($1 in a)
' Input_file2 FS='|' Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v s1='"' '                        ##Starting awk program from here and creating variable s1 whose value is ".
FNR==NR{                               ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named Input_file2 is being read.
  val=s1 $0 s1                         ##Creating variable val whose value is s1 current line value and s1 here.
  a[val]                               ##Creating an array named a whose index is variable val.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                      ##Closing FNR==NR BLOCK of this code here.
($1 in a)                              ##Checking condition if $1 of current line is present in array a then print that line of Input_file1.
' Input_file2 FS='|' Input_file1       ##Mentioning Input_file2 then setting FS as pipe and mentioning Input_file1 name here.
```

Comment: above command is working for non double quote ids but with quotes is not working. do i need to update anything to work both scenarios in one command.

Comment: @rakeshkandukuri, Ok could you please try following `awk -v s1='"' 'FNR==NR{val=s1 $0 s1;a[val];b[$0];next} ($1 in a) || ($1 in b)' Input_file2 FS="|" Input_file1` and lemme know then?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your input is

```
"1"|data|er
"2"|text|rq
""|test2|req
"3"|test4|teq
```

And you want from these information 2 types of data :

- The ids
- The lines containing an id

The easiest way to achieve this is, I think, to first get lines that has id, then from this, retrieve the ids.

To do so :

```sh
$ awk -F'|' '$0 ~ /"[0-9]+"/' input1 >input3; cat input3
"1"|data|er
"2"|text|rq
"3"|test4|teq
$ sed 's/^"//; s/".*$//' input3 >input2; cat input2
1
2
3
```

Comment: awk -F''$Delimeter'' '{print $1}' file1.txt | awk '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); print $1}' | awk  'NF && !seen[$1]++' | sort -n > file2.txt  --> this command extracts the 1 2 3 ids from file1. but problem is i need to search these ids in file1.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ? And, by the way, I don't understand neither what you want with this command ? You want ids and the lines to be ordered by id ?